# More efficient way of parsing value data from structured stream dataframe in pyspark3

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am fetching pyspark stream data:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

raw_stream = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("endpoint", conf.get('config', 'endpoint')) \
    .option("app.name", conf.get('config', 'app_name')) \
    .option("app.secret", conf.get('config', 'app_key')) \
    .option("dc", conf.get('config', 'dc')) \
    .option("source.topic", conf.get('config', 'topic')) \
    .option("group.name", conf.get('config', 'group')) \
    .option("source.value.binaryType", 'false') \
    .load()

raw_stream_str = raw_stream \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

value_batch = raw_stream_str \
    .writeStream \
    .queryName("value_query") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()

spark.sql("select * from value_query").show()
```

which output is as below:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{"message":"DGc6K...|
+--------------------+
```

The whole content of value looks like that:

```
[Row(value='{"message": "xxx", "source": "xxx", "instance": "xxx", "metrics": {"metric1": "xxx", "metric2": "xxx", ...}}')]
```

where metrics is a dictionary like key-value pairs. I want to extract metrics content so I have something like that:

```
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|metric1|metric2|            metric3|
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|  "abc"|  12345|01/01/2022 00:00:00|
+-------+-------+-------------------+
```

I am able to achieve it by considering it as a list of string:

```
raw_stream_str.selectExpr("value", "split(value,',')[3] as message").drop("value")
raw_stream_str.selectExpr("metrics","split(value,',')[0] as metric1"...).drop("metrics")
```

Is there more efficent (spark) way of doing it in terms of distributed computing? Maybe by applying/mapping some function on every row of stream output dataframe with the help of json.loads so I can explore its key-value nature?

Comment: [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark-sql-functions-from-json) function takes in a column that has json string and parses based on the provided schema.

Comment: @samkart thanks, there are many keys in the value and it may change constantly. Can I do it without providing a schema?

Comment: you could try it with a udf that parses based on json.loads

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can use `from_json` to get the data in the required schema and after that you can do `df.select("metrics.*")` to get the required dataframe.

Comment: Should I use `from_json` two times? first to extract message column from value and second time is to extract columns from message? Can I do it without providing a schema? Is there a function so it can read schema from the data?

Comment: Because there are few topics and its structure might change frequently. I am only interested in columns in metrics.

Comment: can I implement it when reading a stream? something like 
```
.readStream \
...
.load() \
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
.parse my value data \
.parse metrics data \
.select("metrics.*")\
```
would it be executed in disturbed manner across cluster or only on driver node? Thanks!

Comment: I am trying it with 
```
    json_schema = StructType([StructField("value", StringType(), True)]) 
    ...
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .withColumn('value', from_json(col('value'), json_schema))
```
which gives me {null} in value column

Comment: When you read the json from file, it will automatically infer the schema. So, you can do, spark.read.json("<json_path>").select("value.*").select("metrics.*") to get the required df.

Comment: I was able to implement it in this way:
1. provide a schema
value_schema = StructType([StructField("metric", StringType(), True)])
metrics_schema = StructType([StructField("metric1", StringType(), True), StructField("metric3", StringType(), True)])
2. add this lines to readStream:
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .withColumn('value', from_json(col('value'), value_schema)) \
    .withColumn('metrics', from_json(col('value.metrics'), metrics_schema)) \
    .select(col('metrics.*'))
This gives me expected output: specific cols of metrics column in value

Comment: Thanks, I am reading data from structured streams not from json file. And in structured stream the data is json like strings. I have a question: 1) is the code above is executing on the cluster or on a single driver node? 2) Is it because of the json like structure of the data I can provide the only columns I want to extract when defining a schema in StructType. And no need to provide other columns when providing a schema.

Comment: You don't need to specify the schema second time. You can simply do, .load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").withColumn('value', from_json(col('value'), value_schema)).select(col('metrics.*')). To answer your 1st question , till we are doing transformation nothing will happen. When you take an action(i.e., writing to an external sink), then the code will be distributed to executors and run. For your 2nd question, you can specify the only the required columns in the schema and spark will read the columns based on the specified schema. This is true for json and other types e.g. csv, parquet

Comment: Thanks, when I am running `value_schema = StructType([StructField("value", StringType(), True)])
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .withColumn('value', from_json(col('value'), value_schema)) \
    .select(col('metrics.*'))` it gives me this error: `cannot resolve 'metrics.*' given input columns 'value'` and when I change it to specific column name like: `.select(col('metrics.metric1')` it gives me another error: `Column 'metrics.metric1' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [value];` when I do specify scheme two times it works fine though

Comment: Sorry, I missed one select clause..try this .load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").withColumn('value', from_json(col('value'), value_schema)).select("value.*").select(col('metrics.*'))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247500/discussion-between-azamat-and-kvj).